# Horizontal file concatenation

Tags: text-processing

Is there a Linux command like `cat` that joins files with the same number of lines horizontally?

Comment: It took me a LONG time to find this question!  It seems "horizontal" is the only way to find an answer to this problem.  All the other "duplicates" when I searched for "concatenate columns with awk", etc., only led to database join with awk.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`paste` may do the trick.

```
% cat t1 
a
b
c
c
d
f
g
% cat t2 
h
i
j
k
l
m
n
% paste t1 t2 
a       h
b       i
c       j
c       k
d       l
f       m
g       n
```

At least some of the time, you don't need to have a "key" to concatenate the lines.

Comment: As seen in the example above, the default delimiter is TAB... For no delimiter: `paste -d '\0' t1 t2`

Comment: will this work for files that are gigabytes in size?

Comment: @SARose I don't know. Give it a try and leave a comment about the results.

Answer (score 5):

[`join`](http://www.albany.edu/~ig4895/join.htm) should do the trick - You just need to prefix the lines with an identical ID.